# Is it possible to update the GitLab path? ie. https://change.this.path/username --> https://updated.new.path/username

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to update the path? The issue is that when I created the GitLab account I used my personal email address for work. Now that I no longer work there the path is still associated with work. From the image below it's the part in the red box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, from the server admin section.

is not user related but global

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab

Comment: Hmm...I wonder if using the omnibus package is the only way. Since I don't have this downloaded on my local let me see if there's an alternative.

Comment: if you are not omnibus i think you can do it manually: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/google_cloud_platform/#using-a-domain-name